# Mouse is choppy

Tags: 11.10, mouse, cursor

When I installed Ubuntu (11.10) a few days ago, my mouse cursor was smooth and responsive. Now it's very slow, choppy, and clumsy. I hadn't really changed much (at least I don't think so), all I've really done is just install Ubuntu and install of all its updates. I'm pretty sure it just started happening the first or second time I rebooted.

I'm very new to Linux, and don't even know where to begin. Can anyone offer some assistance?

System info:

- Intel 920 i7 @ 3.6GHz (2.66 stock)
- 6GB DDR3 RAM
- 2x Radeon HD 6860 (I haven't done anything to enable Crossfire in
  Ubuntu, though)
- WD 120GB HDD

Thank you.

Comment: If you look inside the ubuntu software center you will see a history button. Try and see if a new kernel has been installed on your machine or new xorg-xinput-* packages have been installed recently. This might narrow it down. Additionally, try loading the livecd of 11.10 and see if there is an issue. If there isn't, then something indeed has changed. If the livecd exhibits the same problem, that points more towards hardware problems sadly.

Comment: Optical mice can pick up even small pieces of lint in the optic port. Turn the mouse over and blow it out even if you don't see anything. Another problem I've seen is the finely textured surfaces on plastic mouse pads wear and give erratic results. Try a sheet of printer paper -- it will always work smoothly on the paper. May not be your issues but simple enough to check.

Comment: See if any process ate up CPU in system monitor..?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Bluetooth Mouse and have high Wi-Fi traffic, this could be the cause. There are bugs tracked in launchpad for different hardware.
If you don't download stuff with extreme speed, but suffer this problem, then it's something different.